# linux терминал. Найти все каталоги, содержащие файлы определённые файлы, вывести по одному разу

Tags: linux

Подскажите как вывести все каталоги, содержащие некие файлы заданные по маске, и вывести эти каталоги по одному разу. Например искать все папки, где есть файлы начинающиеся на А или формата .txt. Уже перепробовал всё с find, если не хотите команду целиком писать, подскажите хоть в каком направлении искать.

Comment: imho, надо на bash писать, что-то более сложное, чем одна строка, хотя я пишу на node.js+shelljs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find -iname '*.txt' | xargs -d'\n' dirname | uniq
```